# how to see the (always) updated render result in the image editor?

Tags: rendering

Is it possible to always see the rendered result after compositing in the image editor? I know it shows it if i hit F12, but i want to do it automatically.

"Update autmatically" is checked. I am rendering with Eevee.

Comment: Your problem is that you see the image before composition in the image editor ?

Comment: My problem is that it isn’t updated at all, only if I hit F12. But I would like to see it after compositor.